# self.present doesn't work after POST request

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create a page with server connection.

A simple POST (email and password fields) and upon response, I need to show an alert to the user.

This line causes an exception:

```
self.present(alerta2, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Here is my code:

```
request.httpMethod = "POST" // Compose a query string
let postString = "email=" + userEmail + "&password=" + userPassword
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if error != nil {
        self.mostraAlerta(mensagem: "Ocorreu um erro!")
        return
    }

    // Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        // print(json)
        if let parseJSON = json {
            let status = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            let msg = parseJSON["msg"] as? String
            let titulo = parseJSON["titulo"] as? String
            switch status {
            case "0"?:
                let alerta2 = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: msg!, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                alerta2.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alerta2, animated: true, completion: nil)
                // print("Status: OK")
                break
            case "1"?:
                print("Status: " + msg!)
                break
            default:
                print("Status: N/D")
                break
            }
            // print("Status: \(status)")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

The exception:

[image]

The error:

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill: 0x110b48d38
>   <+0>: movl $0x2000148, %eax ; imm = 0x2000148 0x110b48d3d
>   <+5>: movq %rcx, %r10 0x110b48d40
>   <+8>: syscall -> 0x110b48d42
>   <+10>: jae 0x110b48d4c ; <+20> 0x110b48d44
>   <+12>: movq %rax, %rdi 0x110b48d47
>   <+15>: jmp 0x110b41caf ; cerror_nocancel 0x110b48d4c
>   <+20>: retq 0x110b48d4d
>   <+21>: nop 0x110b48d4e
>   <+22>: nop 0x110b48d4f
>   <+23>: nop

Comment: Can you post what the excpetion says?

Comment: `self.present(alerta2, animated:true, completion:nil)` need to be done in main thread because it's related to UI.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I am really new with SWIFT, so I am following some copied code...

Comment: The error:

libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x110b48d38 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x110b48d3d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x110b48d40 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x110b48d42 <+10>: jae    0x110b48d4c               ; <+20>
    0x110b48d44 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x110b48d47 <+15>: jmp    0x110b41caf               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x110b48d4c <+20>: retq   
    0x110b48d4d <+21>: nop    
    0x110b48d4e <+22>: nop    
    0x110b48d4f <+23>: nop

Comment: Edit your question and put there the full error message.

Comment: What you need to put is the text in the debugger, that's the important one. Where there is "terminating with uncaught"..."

Comment: Click on the pointy arrow-looking icon under the run/stop buttons in the upper left of your Xcode window. The resulting panel shows any breakpoints you have set. At the bottom left of that panel, click the `+` button. Click to create an Exception breakpoint, then click somewhere else to close the window that comes up (the default values are fine). Then, run your project again. This will stop exactly where the exception is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the error and the fix.

The error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue
>   waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.

The solution:

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
    self.present(alerta2, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```